# Troubleshooting Generic "Script Error" On A WordPress Websites In GA4

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-analytics-4

I'm using GA4 to log JavaScript errors for one of the websites I manage.  Over the last month there's been about 1700 generic "script errors" logged in GA4.  When researching this issue, it looks like a generic Script Error is thrown when a cross domain script encounters an error.  I suspect this is an issue with a HubSpot tracking code or a similar marketing type script that I don't have access to modify and that is a cross origin script. They are happening on contact page most frequently though and I am concerned that form submits are being blocked.  Any suggestions for how to go about troubleshooting which file may have generated the errors or how to troubleshoot these types of errors?